# Find a sum x from elements from 4 differens sequences

Tags: algorithm, performance, sum, sequences

This is My problem:

Given a number x and 4 sequences A, B, C and D, each of n numbers, decide whether there exists some numbers a from A, b from B, c from C and d from D such that x = a+b+c+d. Operations alowed are comparisons, additions and swaps. Design an efficient algorithm to solve this problem with a worst case running time less than n^4.

I have no idea where to start and would appreciate some help!

Comment: do you need to find every combination for that?

Comment: They don't need to find every combination, just the one that satisfies x = a+b+c+d. Checking every combination would find a solution if there was one with worst case running time less than n^4 however. I think they might want an improvement on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. create pair-sums arrays AB=A+B, CD=C+D by summing every pair between A and B and the same for C and D (AB and CD are arrays of n^2 elements each) - **O(n^2)**
2. Sort arrays AB, CD - **O(n^2 log(n))**   (credit to [user58697](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3403834/user58697) for this approach. Earlier I had suggested a different approach that I thought would have better complexity, but (s)he pointed out my mistake.)
3. Assign indices abi = (n^2-1), cdi = 0
4. Investigate AB[abi]+CD[cdi], check conditions and increment/decrement indices

   1. Compute sum=AB[abi]+CD[cdi]
   2. If sum equals x: SUCH COMBINATION EXISTS! (stop algorithm)
   3. If sum < x: increment cdi (++cdi)
   4. If sum > x: decrement abi (--abi)
   5. If (abi < 0) OR (cdi >= n^2): NO SUCH COMBINATION EXISTS! (stop algorithm)
   6. Go back to 4.1.

   Every time we do step 4 an index is either incremented or decremented (or the algorithm stops) so we are doing step 4 at most 2*n^2 times (the number of elements across both arrays) - **O(n^2)**

So all in all we have **O(n^2 log(n))**

Comment: Right idea but... computing the minimum is `O(n)`, so the merge phase is `O(n^3)`. Using priority queue would make it `O(n^2 log(n))`. This is also achieved by much simpler approach: skip step 1; compute `AB=A+B` as a linear array, and sort it; same for `CD`; follow steps 3 and 4.

Comment: You are right about the minimum, I'll update that. But note that sorting a n^2 sized array is O(n^2 log(n^2)) so your priority queue is better if it yields O(n^2 log(n)) complexity.

Comment: `log(n^2) = 2 log(n)`. It only affects an asymptotic constant, which we know pretty much nothing about.